# How to disconnect from AnyConnect VPN without losing the whole internet connection and having to reboot?

Tags: windows, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

I'm using Cisco Secure Client and I use AnyConnect in it in order to connect to a VPN.

It works totally okay but the problem shows up a couple of moments after I disconnect the VPN I lose my internet connection **in a way that I can't reach any websites or use apps and not even able to connect to the VPN again unless I restart the computer**.

I found somewhere in Reddit that somebody had posted this piece of code and claimed that it acts like rebooting.

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

But I believe that this piece of code doesn't belong to Windows. It's  used for Linux.

I think if I could find the equivalent for that code in Windows, that would work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [`ipconfig /release && ipconfig /renew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig)

Comment: @JW0914 It didn't solve the problem. I alos tried troubleshooting problems of my network adapters before rebooting the computer to see if that works, It also found that there is a problem and it tried reseting the network adapter. It didn't solve the problem as well. I also tried this `ipconfig /flushdns` and it didn't work. Finally I had to reboot the computer and rebooting worked like it used to. I'm wondering if I could find out what exactly happens when I reboot the computer. I want to do that manually without having to reboot the computer. sorry for making the answer so long